# MultiLine String can be null, how to hide it

Tags: swift

I am using multiline string as follows. there is a line where I display `submittedPerson`, either can be his `Id` or `email`, but also can be `nil` as well. I wonder how do you hide this line if it returns `nil`

```
var submittedPerson = ""
if let Id = User[index].Id {
  submittedPerson = Id
} else if let email = User[index].email {
  submittedPerson = email
}

let displayStr = """
              \(department)
             
              \"submittedBy" : \(submittedPerson)

              \(submittedDate)

              """
```

Comment: What do you mean by "null"? Do you mean `nil` or the string `"null"`?

Comment: @Sweeper I think he means `nil` as in, nothing at all

Comment: yes, it might be `nil`. Neither I might have `id` nor `email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the hidden requirement here is that you still want to keep the multiline string literal readable, and not have code duplication :)

One way you could do this is to move one of the two line feed characters to when you assign to `submittedPerson`:

```
var submittedPerson: String? = ""
if let Id = User[index].Id {
  submittedPerson = "\n\(Id)\n" // note the lines feeds
} else if let email = User[index].email {
  submittedPerson = "\n\(email)\n"
}
let displayStr = """
              \(department)
              \(submittedPerson ?? "")
              \(submittedDate)

              """
```